# Why "=" Operator not giving the expected result in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I am trying to get the row from the Database which saves the date in the following format `2018-07-09 13:22:40`

When I write the following query like this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time_col = '2018-07-09 13:22:40';
```

it returns a single row

But When I write a query like this (no result):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time_col = '2018-07-09';
```

it returns me nothing.

For the other operators, it works for  `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` with the following query but why not with "=" Operator

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time_col < '2018-07-09';
```

Comment: Second query will check like this time_col = 2018-07-09 12:00:00 so it wont satisfied
Second query will check like this time_col < 2018-07-09 12:00:00, if there is any data before july 9 then it will return

Comment: @Gaj: it will check the value at midnight: `2018-07-09 00:00:00`, not at noon

Comment: i said in 12 hrs format

Comment: @Gaj: if you specify a value like ` 2018-07-09 12:00:00` in SQL it is **not** in 12-hours format. That's the ISO format which is a 24hour based format

Comment: in oracle if we set nls_date_format to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss then it will take 12hrs format only. anyway it wont applicable for postgres.. now only i saw the postgres tag

Comment: @Gaj: even in Oracle you should **not** rely on the evil implicit data type casting. You should either use a proper ANSI SQL timestamp literal or `to_timestamp()` **with** a format mask matching your input. Do **not** rely on `nls_date_format`. That's begging for problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column is of type `timestamp`, then the string constant `'2018-07-09'` will be converted to a timestamp by Postgres - but with the time as `00:00:00`.

So the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time_col = '2018-07-09';
```

is actually run as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time_col = timestamp '2018-07-09 00:00:00';
```

Which of course does not match the value `2018-07-09 13:22:40`.

To get the rows on a specific day, you can cast the timestamp column to a date:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time_col::date = date '2018-07-09'
```

This will however prevent the usage on the `time_col` column. So if that version of the query is slow, you have to revert to a range query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE time_col >= timestamp '2018-07-09 00:00:00'
  and time_col < timestamp '2018-07-10 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work cause column is timestamp (date with time). But you trying compare that with date(no date), that is why they are not equal.

Use trunc function in oracle. trunc function cuts time from date and leaves only date:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE trunc(time_col) = '2018-07-09';
```

And for postgres use explicit cast:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE time_col::date = '2018-07-09';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *FROM table
WHERE update_date >= '2013-05-03'::date
AND update_date < ('2013-05-03'::date + '1 day'::interval);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please say something about why this works and how it is different than the OP code.